# Is there a way to respec my skills?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

As it happened to me in pretty much every RPG I played, it turns out that my initial choices of skills weren't exactly ideal. The first character I meet has exactly the same skill at maximum level that I have. The second I meet also has this skill as his highest. This in turn means that I currently have no character that has focused entirely on mechanics, only a bunch of characters at a reasonably high, but not high enough level for the traps I'm encountering right now.

Is there a way to respec skills? I'd prefer an ingame mechanic, but I would consider using a cheat, console command or editor as I just want to switch around skills, not increase the absolute amount.

Answer (score 1):

There's currently no in game mechanic to do this. While there are save editors and cheats (or were during the Backer Beta - I don't know of anything updated for release), do keep in mind that use of either can disable all Steam achievements (though this is fixable.)

Comment: Cheating part is wrong - using CheatEngine tables allowes you to modify stats without loosing achievements. Bah, one of them allows to restore gaining Steam achievements to a game that already lost that ability due to using in-game console.